# Solr/solrnet - popular searches

Tags: solr, solrnet

can anyone tell me if there is a way to retrieve a list of popular searches in solr and/or solrnet?

Thanks in advance

jp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Solr doesn't implement anything like that. It's entirely up to you to gather/retrieve this information.